# Show $\phi(n)$ = $n \Pi_{p \vert n} (1 - \frac{1}{p})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

(Here $\phi$ is the Euler Totient Function, $p$ all the primes dividing $n$) So I wanted to know is the best way to prove this using induction on $n$? or to suppose cases where $n$ is prime or composite? which would be the best approach? I am lost on how to approach this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

> Let $p$ be a prime such that $p \not\mid n$, then $$\phi(pn)=(p-1)·\phi(n)$$
>   Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\mid n$, then $$\phi(pn)=p·\phi(n)$$

Prove and apply these properties to all prime factors of $n$.

Comment: Wot thanks, so to clarify, induction was not the way to go? using these properties of the function together with my assumption of suppose $n$ is prime or composite (prime case is trivial) and the composite case I apply your hint, THANKS!!!

Comment: Induction might also be a way, but I think that this one is easier ;)

Comment: awesome thank you so much!!